# Search for an unknown child key in Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to add a `ValueEventListener` by going though an unknown child in firebase for android?

What I've tried so far is something like this:

```
reference
    .child("data")
    .child(/*unknown_key*/)
    .orderByChild("contacts")
    // etc...
```

Where at the "unknown_key" I've tried many options, such as `"{placeholder}"`, `"{*}"` or `"*"`

This is somehow possible in Firebase Functions, by passing a generic node in the URL, such as `https://myfirebaseproj.firebase.com/data/{any}/contacts`

I know that I could just get the children under the `data/` node and do some iterations, but this feels overkill to me, since the node could really be big and the cost is expontential.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON that you're trying to query (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). So a single snippet from `data` to `contacts` with all levels of JSON in between.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I can't export my json as of right now, but i think you can get a basic idea of the nodes. It is really as simple as I wrote it, I have some objects under the contacts node and that's it, I want to search by these objects key. I temporary solved it by using a ChildEventListener which seems to be working as I intended. Thank you!